# Card-related question on standard deviation

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> You pick randomly $26$ cards out of $52$ without replacement. What is the standard deviation of this choice if to each card we assign a number from $1$ to $13$, that is ace $=1 $, king $= 1$ etc.

Any hints on this problem? I also wondered, whether the following formulation would be equivalent for $n = 13$.

> Consider a collection of $4n$ numbers containing $4$ copies of each number from $1$ to $n$. You pick randomly $2n$ numbers from that collection without replacement. What is the standard deviation of this choice?

My confusion regarding the equivalence of the problem concerns the fact whether the distribution of choices in two cases are different. In the second case we do not distinguish between the same numbers, whereas in the first case the same number is corresponding to clearly distinguishable cards.

Comment: Haha is it a coincidence that your username is "S.D."? Anyway the first problem is not very well formulated; it seems to imply that the cards are assigned numbers independently of each other. In that case it is clearly different from the second problem, because in the first we can draw 13 "1"s but not in the second.

Comment: @user21820: thanks for the comment, I made the first formulation more clear.

Comment: Okay now that you've changed the first problem it is equivalent. It matters not whether you can distinguish the copies of the same number, because in the end you measure something that doesn't. If you wanted to you could attach a label to your numbers in the second problem, which allows you to distinguish the copies of each number but clearly doesn't change the probability distributions involved.

Comment: I outlined how to answer the first question no more than a month ago, probably much less. And the procedure readily generalizes. To my surprise, [I have found it!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788104/variance-of-26-cards-chosen-from-a-deck)

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thanks, I've asked my question regarding your solution there.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read your problem, yes, the two are equivalent.  With replacement this would be trivial.

Without replacement you have to consider the dependence across picks, but you appear to have a solution for that problem already.

Comment: *you appear to have a solution for that problem already* can you elaborate, please?