# Drawing without replacement yields identically distributed sequences

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

This question is inspired by my interest in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/788215/20309) by Andre, and is related to advancing my background in combinatorics overall.

How can we show formally the following fact. If we draw $X_1,\dots,X_m$ from a collection of $n$ arbitrary entities without replacement $(n\geq m)$, then distribution of $(X_{i_1},\dots,X_{i_k})$ for $i_1,\dots,i_k$ ($m \geq k$) pairwise distinct depends only on $k$ but not $i_1,\dots,ik$.

Here I mean that $X_1$ is the first draw, it takes any value among $n$ entities with probability $\frac1n$. $X_2$ is the second draw which is any of $n-1$ left entities with probability $\frac1{n-1}$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution is completely determined by the set of valid subcollections that you can obtain and their probabilities. But it is clear that for each collection of $m$ items, any permutation of that collection is equally probable. Hence a subcollection from it with a certain sequence of $k$ indices in $[1..m]$ has the same probability as with any other sequence of $k$ indices in $[1..m]$, because we could simply permute the whole collection to make the first sequence of indices map to the second. Hence the joint distribution of the elements in the subcollection is independent of the choice of the $k$ indices.

Comment: I personally believe that this is the best way to understand this phenomenon of symmetry, because firstly it is intuitive, and secondly it is rigorous and explicitly shows where the condition of drawing each element uniformly randomly from the $n$ items is used, exactly where I claim that any permutation of a given collection is equally probable. This type of argument can be used to prove many algorithms, such as generating a uniform random permutation.