# Standard Deviation of 26 Cards

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, card-games

What is the standard deviation for 26 cards drawn from a standard deck (each card's value ranges between 1 and 13)? Assume selection is with replacement.

I saw someone approach this problem by summing the variance for one card 26 times and then taking the square root. However, isn't this approach wrong as we are looking for the standard deviation of the 26 cards and not of the sum of the 26 cards?

Here is my approach by using the mean of the sum of the 26 cards:

Var(X) = Var((X1 + X2 + ... X26)/26) = (1/26^2) (26 * Var(X1)) = (1/26^2) (26 * 14)

Var(X) = 14/26. This is wrong, however.

Comment: You are drawing without replacement, I assume?  So in that case, a $52$ card sample is determined, hence has variance $0$.  Not $52$ times the variance of a single card sample.  The different draws simply aren't independent, so the naive summation doesn't work.

Comment: Assume with replacement

Comment: Oh, well if you are replacing, then each draw is independent so Variance is indeed additive.  But you should edit your post for clarity.  I don't know that your readers are likely to guess you meant to draw with replacement.

Comment: The standard deviation for 26 cards drawn from a standard deck is a random variable.  If you mean the sample standard deviation, this random variable ranges from 0 to about 5.04.  If you mean the population standard deviation, it ranges from 0 to about 4.94.  But presumably you don't want the random variable itself:  that would require specifying the probability of it taking all the various values it can take.  You might mean the mean of it.  Or you might intend the square root of mean of the variance.  Or perhaps the standard deviation of the average of the cards.  Please clarify.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming without replacement when citing 5.04 and 4.94.

Comment: But why would you be adding the variance? We are not looking for the variance of the sum of the 26 cards, we are looking for the variance of the 26 cards.

Comment: What the heck do you mean by the variance of a collection, if not the variance of the sum?

Comment: Same question as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788104/variance-of-26-cards-chosen-from-a-deck

Comment: So if X is the sum, we are looking for Var(X/26)

Comment: Well, that's just $\frac {\text {Var}(X)}{26^2}$, so there's no real difference between the mean and the sum, you can easily pass from one to the other.

Comment: That is the answer that I have posted (14/26). However, by Monte Carlo simulation, it is 13.72. What am I missing here? You can compare my solution with the solution provided in the linked post. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the linked post specifically refers to a process "without replacement".  As has been mentioned, that choice is critical.

Comment: However, shouldn't the value still be close to the value in our case? How is the value there 13.72 as opposed to 14/26 here?

Comment: @Anon $14/26$ is the variance of the sample mean.  $14$ is the expectation of the sample variance. Not the same thing - see my answer which simulates both.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may be confusing the variance of the sample mean with the expectation of the sample variance.

The variance for the value of one card drawn uniformly from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ with equal probability is $\frac{13^2-1}{12}=14$.

So drawing $26$ cards independently with replacement, the variance of the sample sum sum is $26 \times 14=364$ and the variance of the sample mean is $\frac{14}{26} \approx 0.538$. The standard deviations are the square roots of these.

If instead you are interested in the expectation of the sample variance then, if you are using Bessel's correction it is $14$, and if you do not then it is $14 \times \frac{26-1}{26}\approx 13.46$. The expected standard deviation is not the square root of this but slightly less, as square root is not a linear function.

Here is a simulation in R demonstrating this (with a little simulation noise):

```
set.seed(2023)
samplesome <- function(values, samplesize, replacement){
   x <- sample(values, samplesize, replace=replacement)
   return(c(sum(x), mean(x), var(x), sd(x)))
   }
sims <- replicate(10^5, samplesome(rep(1:13,4), 26, TRUE))
var(sims[1,])   # variance of sample sums
# 362.7971
var(sims[2,])   # variance of sample means
# 0.536682
mean(sims[3,])  # mean of sample variances
# 14.00217
mean(sims[4,])  # mean of sample standard deviations
# 3.726031
```

An interesting point is that sampling half the deck *without replacement*, you roughly halve the variance of the sample sum and sample mean (they become $26\times 14\times\frac{52-26}{52-1}\approx 185.6$ and $\frac{14}{26}\times\frac{52-26}{52-1}\approx 0.275$) while the sample variance would appear to increase slightly (Bessel's correction is too strong in this case, and clearly if you sampled the whole deck the sample sum and sample mean would have zero variance while the sample variance with no correction would be exactly $14$).  Replacing `TRUE` in the code above by `FALSE` would give

```
var(sims[1,])   # variance of sample sums
# 185.9986
var(sims[2,])   # variance of sample means
# 0.2751459
mean(sims[3,])  # mean of sample variances
# 14.27443
mean(sims[4,])  # mean of sample standard deviations
# 3.770068
```

Comment: Could u plss explain where u got the (52-26)/(52-1) when sampling half the deck without replacement? Thanks

Comment: @quantrader23 This is called the "finite population correction" $\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$.   You can find a derivation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/514259/2958